# Grep examples - can't understand

Tags: unix, grep

Given the following commands:

```
ls | grep ^b[^b]*b[^b]

ls | grep ^b[^b]*b[^b]*
```

I know that ^ marks the start of the line, but can anyone give me a brief explanation about 
these commands? what do they do? (Step by step)

thanks!

Comment: `[^b]` - means a character that is not `b`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^` can mean two things:

- mark the beginning of a line
- ***or*** it negates the character set (whithin `[]`)

So, it means:

- lines starting with 'b'
- matching any (0+) characters Other than 'b'
- matching another 'b'
- followed by something not-'b' (or nothing at all)

It will match

```
bb
bzzzzzb
bzzzzzbzzzzzzz
```

but not

```
zzzzbb
bzzzzzxzzzzzz
```

Comment: Yup. Or, more usefully: `[^0-9]`

Comment: (At least) in this context (ls | grep), it does match `bzzzzbb`, as  it only checks the beginnings of filenames. To exclude `bzzzzbb`, you'd have to use `^b[^b]*b[^b]*$`

Comment: @MikeHartl Ah, you're right. My error was, thinking the second b is followed by a `b`, which is expressly prohibited. It isn't: it just matches '0' occurences for the second `[^b]*`... :)

Answer (score 0):

1)starts with b and name continues with a 0 or more characters which are not b and then b and then continues with a character which is not b

2)starts with b and name continues with a 0 or more characters which are not b and then b and then continues with 0 or more characters which are  not b